# Showing dimension is less than or equal to n

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ is algebraic of degree n. Regard $\mathbb{C}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space, and consider the subspace $W$=span$\{1,\beta, \beta^2,\beta^3...\}$.
Show that the dimension of $W \leq n$ and that $W$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

I'm stumped with this one as I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: If $\beta$ is algebraic of degree $n$, then can you see that the first $n$ powers of $\beta$ are linearly dependent as vectors of $W$?

Answer (score 1):

You know that $\beta$ is algebraic of degree $n$, which is another way of saying that there is a degree $n$ polynomial $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $p(\beta) = 0$ (assume that this polynomial is irreducible). Note that since $p(\beta) = a_n \beta^n + \cdots + a_0 = 0$, you can write $\beta^n$ (and as such all higher powers) in terms of a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of $\{1, \beta, \beta^2,...,\beta^{n-1}\}$. Can you show that $1, \beta, \beta^2,...,\beta^{n-1}$ are linearly independent?

To show that its a field, you should look at the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$. Is this enough to help?